# Vis viva equation: Error in the wikipedia derivation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

If I the [derivation of the vis viva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) equation from wikipedia, I don't see of how this derivation works for circular orbits. In a circular orbit it is $r_a = r_b$ and $v_a = v_b$ and already the starting point, i.e. the conservation of energy contains no content at all:

$$
\varepsilon = \frac{v_a^2}{2} - \frac{GM}{r_a} = \frac{v_p^2}{2} - \frac{GM}{r_p} 
$$

So I am right, that this shows that the derivation on wikipedia doesn't work, or did I miss something? If it indeed doesn't work, how to fix the derivation (without altering the main idea of this derivation too much).

Comment: It's true that their derivation only works for non-circular orbits, but the case of a circular orbit is trivial (the vis-viva equation reduces to $v^2 = GM/r$ which is one step away from Newton's laws), so I think that's excusable. You don't need the vis-viva equation for circular orbits.

Comment: In the circular orbit I would get this just be rearranging a centripetal approach: $mv^2/r = GmM/r^2$.

Comment: So I get the feeling that I give some input (centripetal force equation) in the circular case, which I don't seem to need (or a generalization of it) in the general case. The other way around I am wondering why the general derivation breaks down in the most simple case.

Comment: In a non-circular orbit there is some energy exchange between kinetic and potential. Energy conservation says gain in one comes by losing the other. In a circular orbit, no exchange happens.